# Como puedo guardar los datos de una api en Room

Tags: android-studio, api, kotlin, android-room

Actualmente quiero guardar el resultado de una API en una tabla de la base de datos con Room en Android

Este es el resultado de la API

```
 [NetworkOrgs(hpc=null, id=1001 Ideas Para Mi País, idr=1480, name=1001 Ideas Para Mi País), NetworkOrgs(hpc=null, id=3AG, idr=860, name=3AG)]
```

Hasta el momento no logro ingresar esos datos a room.

Esta es mi configuración de la interface Dao

```
import android.content.Context
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.room.*


@Dao
interface OrgsDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM DatabaseOrgs")
    fun getOrgs(): LiveData<List<DatabaseOrgs>>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun inserAll(vararg orgs: DatabaseOrgs)
}
@Database(entities = [DatabaseOrgs::class], version = 1)
abstract class OrgsDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract val orgsDao: OrgsDao
}
private lateinit var INSTANCE: OrgsDatabase

fun getDatabase(context: Context): OrgsDatabase {
    synchronized(OrgsDatabase::class.java) {
        if (!::INSTANCE.isInitialized) {
            INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext,
                OrgsDatabase::class.java,
                "baseDedatosOrgs").build()
        }
    }
    return INSTANCE
}
```

Y aquí configuro los campos para mi tabla.

```
@Entity
data class DatabaseOrgs constructor(
    @PrimaryKey
    val idr: Int,
    val id: String,
    val name: String,
    val hpc: Int?,
)

fun List<DatabaseOrgs>.asDomainModel(): List<OrgsItem> {
    return map {
        OrgsItem(
            idr = it.idr,
            id = it.id,
            name = it.name,
            hpc = it.hpc
        )
    }
}
```

**Pero no logro ingresar los datos al la función del dao de inserAll**

Este es el repositorio con el que debo de ingresar los datos de la API al Room

```
class OrgsRepository (private val database: OrgsDatabase){
    val orgs: LiveData<List<OrgsItem>> =
        Transformations.map(database.orgsDao.getOrgs()){
            it.asDomainModel()
        }

    suspend fun refreshOrgs(){
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
            val orgslist = NetworkOrgsService.respuestaOrgs.getAllOrgs().await()
            Log.i("orgList",orgslist.toString()) **Este es el resultado que muestro al inicio**
//            database.orgsDao.inserAll(*orgslist) **Aqui no logro ingresarlo**
        }
    }
}
```

Tengo dudas si mi posible error es en la interfaz dao en la función de insertAll

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun inserAll(vararg orgs: DatabaseOrgs)
```

Estaba siguiendo el ejemplo "[Developing Android Apps with Kotlin](https://www.udacity.com/course/developing-android-apps-with-kotlin--ud9012?fbclid=IwAR0IVtx5hsiCPG6JYaesJqqZuxHgvBaPaWkGBLIyzkjMMDEQnXS4MQxfLTw)", pero la api que utilizan es un Objeto, en cambio la que yo utilizo el resultado es un Array, es hay donde quedo enredado y no logro ingresar los datos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo pude solucionar.

Cuando solicito la api la solicito como un `List<DatabaseOrgs>`

```
interface OrgsService {
    @GET("orgs.js")
    fun getAllOrgs(): Deferred<Array<DatabaseOrgs>>
}
```

Pero al ingresarlo a la tabla debe ser de tipo Array

Y con el cambio de List a Array almacene los datos correctamente